# Char.toString without special handling of " and \

Tags: escaping, sml, smlnj

I am trying to convert characters into strings like so:

```
Char.toString(#"x")
```

For most characters this works, however for `"` and `\`, an extra `\` is added before it:

```
- Char.toString(#"\"");
val it = "\\\"" : string
```

This is undesirable behavior for me. I want the above code snippet to return `val it = "\"" : string`. Is there any built-in function in SML that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation of `Char.toString`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/char.html#SIG:CHAR.toString:VAL):

> returns a printable string representation of the character, using, if necessary, SML escape sequences. Printable characters, except for #"\" and #"\"", are left unchanged. Backslash #"\" becomes "\\"; double quote #"\"" becomes "\\"". [...]
>
> To convert a character to a length-one string containing the character, use the function [String.str](http://sml-family.org/Basis/string.html#SIG:STRING.str:VAL).

And from the documentation of `String.str`:

> `str c` is the string of size one containing the character c.

So `str #"\""` will do exactly what you want.

Comment: This feature of Char.toString was later reinvented by the PHP group under the name "magic quotes".